# Invalid meta-data produced in META-INF when compiling Kotlin jar with Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I recently faced an internal compiler exception when trying to include a jar (which contains compiled classes from another Kotlin project):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/[myUsername]/.m2/repository/com/my/library/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/library-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/moduleName_main.kotlin_module
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler.contentsToByteArray(ZipHandler.java:233)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.CoreJarVirtualFile.contentsToByteArray(CoreJarVirtualFile.java:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.JvmPackagePartProvider.processNotLoadedRelevantRoots(JvmPackagePartProvider.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.JvmPackagePartProvider.findPackageParts(JvmPackagePartProvider.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:32)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:321)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:362)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment.getBinaryClasses$kotlin_compiler(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:36)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:321)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:362)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getKotlinScopes(JvmPackageScope.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getContributedClassifier(JvmPackageScope.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ChainedMemberScope.getContributedClassifier(ChainedMemberScope.kt:33)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.FileScopeFactory$currentPackageScope$1.getContributedClassifier(FileScopeFactory.kt:153)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.utils.ScopeUtilsKt.findClassifier(ScopeUtils.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.QualifiedExpressionResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(QualifiedExpressionResolver.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(TypeResolver.kt:577)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver$resolveTypeElement$1.visitUserType(TypeResolver.kt:159)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:905)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtUserType.accept(KtUserType.java:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:58)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveTypeElement(TypeResolver.kt:157)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.doResolvePossiblyBareType(TypeResolver.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolvePossiblyBareType(TypeResolver.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:72)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveValueParameters(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:320)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.createValueParameterDescriptors(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.initializeFunctionDescriptorAndExplicitReturnType(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:159)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:394)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:458)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.java:167)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.java:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction.accept(KtNamedFunction.java:48)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.java:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.java:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.createFunctionDescriptors(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:174)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.java:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.analyzeFiles(LazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.java:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:151)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegrationWithCustomContext(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:332)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:126)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:325)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:178)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.compileNotIncremental(Tasks.kt:491)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:364)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:148)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:110)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:155)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:240)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's really curious: this error is thrown only when I'm loading the jar from Maven Local (`gradle build install`) - when I download the same jar from Nexus snapshots, the compiler error does not occur.

However, I investigated the jar and I found out that `moduleName_main.kotlin_module` is indeed absent in `META-INF` - instead, there's a `moduleName_compileKotlin.kotlin_module` file. It seems that Gradle plugin forced the `compileKotlin` suffix instead of expected `main` - and since `compileKotlin` is the name of the compilation task, I'm guessing that the suffix defaults to the Gradle task name.

1. Is that an error in Gradle setup on my part or a compiler/plugin bug?
2. Is there a way to modify `kotlin_module` suffix through Gradle plugin settings?

Comment: Which version of Kotlin are you using?

Comment: The latest stable: `1.0.3`.

Comment: This looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13625 which appears to be fixed in 1.0.4 EAP. Could you try 1.0.4 and check if you still see the problem?

Comment: We've looked into this some more and apparently it's a new problem. Could you please file a YouTrack issue with some details? Thanks!

Comment: I'll check if EAP fixes the issue later, I'm currently at work. However, I managed to create an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13993

Comment: Did you try to build with Kotlin 1.0.2, as mentioned in comments there https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13052 ?

Comment: I cleaned the project, switched to 1.0.2 and then back to 1.0.3. It compiles just fine and now I actually cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with concurrent archives building through both IntelliJ and Gradle - it seems that both use different IDs for `kotlin_module`. Clearing the project (not only through `gradle clean`, but also removing `.gradle` and `.idea`) and temporary changes of project Kotlin dependency seem to help.